# How to change the behaviour of the anchor element from opening new link to call new method in angular 4 by using custom directive?

Tags: angular, ionic2, click, angular-directive

I am developing an ionic app, where I got HTML content from API where I have bind this HTML response to my page view by innerHtml  [API response](http://appcarvers.cloudaccess.host/index.php?option=com_api&app=easysocial&resource=newsfeed&format=raw&target_user=587&key=94b218bab41b81d62034b06092a5ec0bd0b3195a&lang=en).

```js
<span stream-link [innerHTML]="item?.title"></span>
```

And this item.title contains following code in it.

```js
<a href="http://appcarvers.cloudaccess.host/index.php?option=com_easysocial&amp;view=profile&amp;id=587:shirley&amp;Itemid=207" alt="Shirley Setia" class="">Shirley Setia</a></span>
```

I have created one custom directive named 'stream-link' which reads the HTML element, now I trying to make a call on click of this element, instead of the opening that link

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[stream-link]' // Attribute selector
})

export class StreamLink {
    constructor(public element: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {
        renderer.listen(element.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
            let test = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('a');
            console.log("TEST"+test);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually asking here? Are you maybe actually asking how to display and modify the HTML content coming from the API response? What does "change behavor of anchor" mean? I see that for example the `"title"` property of items in the feed contains anchors with `href` values pointing to links on the site where the feed is obtained from. Are you asking how to change those values? If so, then to what? When I have that many questions, then your question could do with some improvement to make all of those points clearer.

Comment: @NeilLunn As you can see I got title property from the API response, but when I click on it always open up in the inappBrowser. I want to change this click behaviour and instead of open that URL, I want to parse that URL and fetch id from that URL and pass it to my page as an attribute so that it will be open in the APP. I hope now you got better Idea

Comment: Edit your question to show what you are presently doing. IMHO you should be parsing/altering the response from the service rather than trying to write directives to display HTML content from external services. And honestly that one statement should tell you where you should be looking for a solution. But edit if you really must.

Comment: ok, will update it